# Custom UserValidator Affects Newly Created User Added to a Role

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, multi-tenant

I'm trying to build a multi tenant application in asp.net core and registered asp.net identity like this:

```
services.AddIdentity<TUserIdentity, TUserIdentityRole>(options => 
{
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
})
.AddUserValidator<MultitenantUserValidator<TUserIdentity>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<TContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

My `MultitenantUserValidator` class:

```
public class MultitenantUserValidator<TUser> : IUserValidator<TUser>
    where TUser : UserIdentity
{
    public async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user)
    {
        bool combinationExists = await manager.Users
        .AnyAsync(x => x.UserName == user.UserName
                    && x.Email == user.Email
                    && x.TenantId == user.TenantId);

        if (combinationExists)
            return IdentityResult.Failed(new IdentityError { Description = "The specified username and email are already registered in the given tentant" });

        return IdentityResult.Success;
    }
}
```

This is a part of my `DbSeedingHelper` Class

```
var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, Users.AdminPassword);

if (result.Succeeded)
{
    // Add user to role
    var userRoleresult = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, AuthorizationConsts.AdministrationRole);
}
```

When it executes the line to add the created user to role, the identity result fails with the error from the `MultitenantUserValidator`: "The specified username and email are already registered in the given tenant".

I don't know why it goes back to the validator when trying to add the already created user to a role. I thought it's only meant to be called when the user is being created. Because of this, I can't add the user to a role. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An identity user is validated whenever it is *updated*, not just when it is created. This is to ensure that the user stays valid at all times.

This obviously means that your validator should be able to verify *existing* users as well. A logic that checks for matching combinations, which would include the current user itself, is obviously not a good idea there.

A better check would be to make sure that there is no user with the same combination *that isn’t the same user*.

```
bool combinationExists = await manager.Users.AnyAsync(x => x.Id != user.Id && …);
```

Note that both user name and email address are usually unique within ASP.NET Core Identity. So it is impossible for users to have two distinct users with the the same user name and email address.

If you want your multi-tenancy to be based on the fact that you can register with a single username/email onto multiple tenants but have a separate identity, then this won’t work with the default setup.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. It didn't occur to me that it should work for an update. I feel embarrassed for not figuring it out myself. But for your point on the multitenancy, I just included the username just to ensure that we have unique users per tenant. But I get your point.